# Chrome OS/Chromebook: How to control user access

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I need to know if it is possible to emulate certain functions of the ChromeOS Management Console through apps.

Basically, I want an app to be able to control certain aspects of the OS without being required to purchase the management console.

I believe there is a way to do it, I just need to know where to start. Can an normal JS extension do it? Pepper app? Native App? Which method will give me access the the settings section of the chrome OS?

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all, of the functionality provided in the settings section is not available to normal apps or extensions.

That's probably not what you wanted to hear. To officially request the chrome team adds the features you need, go to http://crbug.com and make a feature request. You should include more details about exactly what you're trying to do.